# Stale file handle on user mounted fstab defined share

Tags: network-shares, nas, file-sharing, nfs

I have a file server with a NFS server running. `/etc/exports` contains this line for the share:

```
/mnt/datastorev2/data/<username> 192.168.20.*(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check) 192.168.22.*(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

On `/mnt/datastorev2/` a ZFS mirrored file system is mounted.

I've tried these definitions as below inside `/etc/fstab` on my client machine, and am currently using the `systemd` one:

```
192.168.20.72:/mnt/datastorev2/data/<username> /media/<servername>/datastorev2/ nfs rw,noauto,user,_netdev,bg 0 0
192.168.20.72:/mnt/datastorev2/data/<username> /media/<servername>/datastorev2/ nfs noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=10,timeo=14,x-systemd.idle-timeout=1min,user 0 0
```

I'm able to mount the file shares using `thunar` and `dolphin` but after a while the share becomes inaccessible with the message:

> mount.nfs: Stale file handle error

And the message in `thunar`:

> ## Failed to mount "datastorev2".
>
> Error when getting information for file “/media/< servername >/datastorev2”: Stale file handle.

I'm unable to find real information about this problem and can't find what debug info would be of use (or even where to find these)

I'm using `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS` with kernel `4.15.0-51-generic`. NFS on both systems is version 4. (Xubuntu is the specific flavour)

(Sidenote: samba isn't an option for me because of latency and because of he fully linux network it would be a shame to use samba.)

**update**
Executing `sudo service nfs-server restart` on the server fixes the problem and the shares become available again after 2 min on the client.

**update #2**

it seems that it might have something to do with `dolhpin` and `thunar` being used and installed at the same time. I have installed `kubuntu` on the same machine with the same `fstab` definitions but haven't had any problems with any stale file handles yet.